# How can we use as input only one row for each node-cell of a dense layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I will like to ask: How can we use as input only one row of a dataset for each node-cell of a dense layer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The extended version about how to manage multiple inputs and outputs in keras-models:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import time


#Examples...in case of input size of one row only...
input_vector_1=[1,2,3]
input_vector_2=[4,5,6]
input_vector_3=[7,8,9]

#Examples in case of 3000 rows of input...
input_matrix_1=np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(3000,3))
input_matrix_2=np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(3000,3))
input_matrix_3=np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(3000,3))

#Inputs...according to decided input shape...
syote_1=keras.Input(shape=(3000,3))
syote_2=keras.Input(shape=(3000,3))
syote_3=keras.Input(shape=(3000,3))

#Let's make next layer for the network...
valikerros_1=layers.Dense(1)
valikerros_2=layers.Dense(1)
valikerros_3=layers.Dense(1)

#And attach input to this layer...
x1=valikerros_1(syote_1)
x2=valikerros_2(syote_2)
x3=valikerros_3(syote_3)

#Let's make the neural network...
kolmen_syotteen_malli=keras.Model(inputs=[syote_1,syote_2,syote_3],outputs=[x1,x2,x3],name="Special neural network model with three inputs and three outputs")

#And show its strutuce
kolmen_syotteen_malli.summary()

#Also save as a picture...for clearness...
keras.utils.plot_model(kolmen_syotteen_malli,'structure.png',show_dtype=True)

#And let's demonstrate the output:
input_1_in_testing=tf.reshape(input_matrix_1,[1,3000,3])
input_2_in_testing=tf.reshape(input_matrix_2,[1,3000,3])
input_3_in_testing=tf.reshape(input_matrix_3,[1,3000,3])

test_output=kolmen_syotteen_malli([input_1_in_testing, input_2_in_testing, input_3_in_testing])

print("Test output with index 0 for the your testing inputs has a shape: ",test_output[0].shape)
print("Test output with index 1 for the your testing inputs has a shape: ",test_output[1].shape)
print("Test output with index 2 for the your testing inputs has a shape: ",test_output[2].shape)
```

Comment: the number of syote layers (which are 3 ) is based on what?

Comment: Your input has a shape of (n,3) but the input of TimeDistributed should be at least 3D, thus in principle not. But - if you are interested about TimeDistributed, please carefully check is it possible to formulate your data (your problem definition...) to a format where there is e.g. RGB-images with several time-steps. If yes, then, after appropriate modification of your model it is possible to use the TimeDistributed layer, too.

Comment: Answer also to my first comment pls

Comment: the number of syote layers (which are 3 ) is based on what? ---> answer is that the first number in this definition is the number of rows of input_matrix_1 and the second number is number of columns in the input_matrix_1. Change those numbers if your input shape changes - accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import time


#Examples...
input_vector_1=[1,2,3]
input_vector_2=[4,5,6]
input_vector_3=[7,8,9]

#Inputs...
syote_1=keras.Input(shape=(1,3))
syote_2=keras.Input(shape=(1,3))
syote_3=keras.Input(shape=(1,3))

#Let's make next layer for the network...
valikerros_1=layers.Dense(1)
valikerros_2=layers.Dense(1)
valikerros_3=layers.Dense(1)

#And attach input to this layer...
x1=valikerros_1(syote_1)
x2=valikerros_2(syote_2)
x3=valikerros_3(syote_3)

#Let's make the neural network...
kolmen_syotteen_malli=keras.Model(inputs=[syote_1,syote_2,syote_3],outputs=[x1,x2,x3],name="Special neural network model with three inputs and three outputs")

#And show its strutuce
kolmen_syotteen_malli.summary()

#Also save as a picture...for clearness...
keras.utils.plot_model(kolmen_syotteen_malli,'structure.png',show_dtype=True)
```

...you will get a structure like this:

[image]

...you can easily change structure - also test and try - and see the effects by monitoring the corresponding result network structure picture.

Comment: what if i have 3000 rows? i will have to initialize 3000 X { syote_1=keras.Input(shape=(1,3)) } this?

Comment: increase 1 to 3000 in the shape

Comment: in Dense layer or input layer?

Comment: In Input layer.

Comment: I'll add another answer, including clarification about the required shapes.